# Rails link to a new post in a category without going to the category page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have post model and a category model. And when i am in the show page of the model i can create a new post that belongs to the category with:

```
<%= link_to 'New post', new_page_path(:category_id => @category)%>.
```

However i would like you see the list of categories like this:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <h3><%= link_to category.title, category %></h3>
<% end %>
```

And i want by clicking on a category that you go directly to the new post form in that category. Instead of having to go to the category_show page first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To direct the category link to new post form instead of category show page, you can just change the link as follows:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <h3><%= link_to category.title, new_page_path(:category_id => category) %></h3>
<% end %>
```

With this change, when you click on a category you would go directly to the new post form in that category.

Comment: alternatively ....
        ... new_page_path(category) also works just fine